# Why webdriver continuously open for each operation?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am beginner in Selenium, there are two separate .xls file file one for GmailTestSuite.xls and other for objectrepository.xls.

I have created `MainClass`, in it I have written a code which read both .xls file, also I've open the driver in it and perform operation. But problem is that it continuously open new driver but don't perform any operation.

Please suggest and let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
public class MainClass {

    static Properties properties= null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile= new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties= readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite= new ExcelHandler("D:\\GmailTestSuite.xls", "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount= testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows="+rowCount);

        for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++)
        {
            String executable= testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable="+executable);

            if(executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            // exe. the process
                String scenarioName= testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);  
                System.out.println("Scenario Name="+scenarioName);
                ExcelHandler testScenarios= new ExcelHandler("D:\\GmailTestSuite.xls", scenarioName);

                int rowWorkBook1= testScenarios.rowCount();
                for(int j=1; j<rowWorkBook1;j++){
                    String framWork= testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
                    String operation = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); //SendKey
                    String value= testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
                    System.out.println("FRMName="+framWork+",Operation="+operation+",Value="+value);

                    ExcelHandler objectRepository= new ExcelHandler("D:\\objectrepository.xls", "OR");
                    objectRepository.columnData();
                    int rowCount1= testSuite.rowCount();
                    System.out.println("Total Rows="+rowCount1);

                    for(int k=1;k<rowCount;k++){
                        String frameWorkName= objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("Executable"), k);
                        String ObjectName= objectRepository.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
                        String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Locator"), k); //SendKey

                        System.out.println("FrameWorkName="+frameWorkName+",ObjectName="+ObjectName+",Locator="+Locator);

                        //ExcelHandler executeOperation = new ExcelHandler(ObjectName, operation, value);
                        File file= new File("D:\\softs\\FF installed\\FF18\\firefox.exe");
                        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
                        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb,new FirefoxProfile());
                        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
                        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));

                        if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey"))
                        {   
                            we.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
                            we.sendKeys("si@2013");
                        }   

                        if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click"))
                            we.click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No time to write a proper answer, but the obvious thing to point out is that you're creating a `WebDriver` instance inside a loop, so that's why you end up with a gazillion of them open. If you create it just once outside the loops and then call it in the loop, it'd probably be what you're looking for in that case.

Comment: @t0mppa Can you please give me an example of this, I know its an silly question but if you give then it would be helpful for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of guide lines for better formed code:

- Break your code into methods that only do one thing each. That way it's easier to manage and nicely compartmentalized, plus you don't enter into indentation hell with such embedded loop and if structures as the one you have over here.
- Use class variables for things like the `WebDriver` instance, so you can initialize it once and keep calling on it later.
- Don't hard code text into the application, use constants. Then you only need to define the text once and can refer to it multiple times. Makes the code much easier to maintain and change, when you don't have to search and replace through entire class, after some details (like a file path) change.

Also, I'm guessing you meant to do the following:

1. loop the rows in `objectRepository` in the k-loop, instead of looping the rows in the `testSuite` again.
2. get cells from `objectRepository` rather than from `testScenarios` when reading the cells from `objectRepository`

Example:

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\softs\\FF installed\\FF18\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    private static final By EMAIL_INPUT = By.id("Email");
    // other constants

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, scenarioName);

        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMName=" + framWork + ",Operation=" + operation +
                               ",Value=" + value);

            handleObjects(operation);
        }
    }

    private void handleObjects(String operation) {
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("Executable"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkName=" + frameWorkName +
                               ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            operateWebDriver(operation);
        }
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation) {
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(EMAIL_INPUT);

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
            we.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
            we.sendKeys("si@2013");
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
            we.click();
        }
    }
}
```

If `ExcelHandler` is your own implementation, you really should move the `getCell(String s)`  method inside the `readCell()` method to change the call pattern of `handler.readCell(handler.getCell("foo"), i)` into `handler.readCell("foo", i)`. If it's a library you're using, you can always make a helper method:

```
private static String readCell(ExcelHandler handler, String cellName, int row) {
    return handler.readCell(handler.getCell(cellName), row);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Since you're having problems with getting `WebDriver` to work, simplify things and take everything else out of the equation for now. In order to do that let's ignore all the reading data from .xls files. This is where having different methods for different things makes your design shine, since you can just comment one method call instead of having to comment out 50 lines of code from your one mega method.

Changed the above code a bit (just commented call to the other methods out and omitted them from the snippet, moved the line opening the correct page into constructor and rewrote the `operateWebDriver()` method a bit):

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    private static final By EMAIL_INPUT = By.id("Email");
    private static final By PASSWORD_INPUT = By.id("Passwd");
    private static final By SIGN_IN_BUTTON = By.id("signIn");

    private static final String EMAIL = "test@abc.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "test123";

    private WebDriver driver;

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        //main.handleTestSuite();

        main.operateWebDriver("Click", EMAIL_INPUT);
        main.operateWebDriver("SendKey", EMAIL_INPUT, EMAIL);
        main.operateWebDriver("Click", PASSWORD_INPUT);
        main.operateWebDriver("SendKey", PASSWORD_INPUT, PASSWORD);
        main.operateWebDriver("Click", SIGN_IN_BUTTON);
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation, By element) {
        operateWebDriver(operation, element, null);
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation, By element, String keys) {
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(element);

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
            we.sendKeys(keys);
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
            we.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Then once you get `WebDriver` working, you can start reading the data from the files and using it to operate `WebDriver`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply its helping for me but I want to know that with this why Its not send or set the key in text field?

Comment: @user2092132: Edited answer with details how to change your code to focus on getting `WebDriver` to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Actually I want to read all the key from the .xls file, the thing which you given in "Edited" code its I've already tried.
In previous code its print all the data of webElements which is given in "operateWebDriver" method.. problem is in loop where we send keys in if() loop. Please check and suggest.

Comment: I can't help you with code you're not sharing. Showed you how to get the `WebDriver` to work outside of the loop, but since I don't know how your reading classes work or what's inside your .xls files, cannot fix them for you. Your original question was how to get the `WebDriver` working properly in the loop, which I believe I've showed you. If your `operation` variable isn't matching the text on the ifs, then you need to debug your .xls or the reading class, neither of which is possible with the information you've provided.

Comment: i) I hav create ExcelHandler class in these it open the excel and return the no. of columns and rows of the excel sheet, also in main class it read all the properties as you see. ii) In GmailTestSuite.xls I have made 2 workbook name "Suite" and "Login". In suite workbook it goes to the "TestScenario" column and check the column which exe. . After reading exe. scenario say "Login" it redirect to login workbook which contains "FramWorkName", "Operation" and "Value". Same in ObjectRepository.xls it read "ObjectName", "Locator" and "FrameworkName". Now might be u understand what I am triyng 2 ask.

Comment: That much was obvious from your question. But if both the `ExcelHandler` and your handling of `WebDriver` are working, like you said, then what exactly is the issue here? This is starting to get very far from the original question...

Comment: Before loop I am trying to print WebElement & its work fine but its not work in if() loop. rest of the code same which u suggest previously. private void operateWebDriver(String operation){
driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);we = driver.findElement(EMAIL_INPUT);
System.out.println("EMAIL_INPUT" + we);we= driver.findElement(PASSWORD_INPUT);System.out.println("PASSWORD_INPUT" + we);if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")){ we.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
System.out.println("Send key for set email" + we);
 we.sendKeys("sipl@2013");}else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")){
 we.click();
 } }

Comment: Move the `driver.get()` to the constructor, so it doesn't always reload the page on every operation. Also, you're assigning the variable `we` twice, so it forgets the first assignment and goes with the second. Use two different variables to store both the field for email and the field for password.

Comment: i) I have put the driver.get() to the constructor, so reloading problem of the page is resolved. ii) As you say assign the value on two different variables I've did it but still its not sending the key in email and password text field.

Comment: Have you checked that execution actually enters the if clause?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it but its not enter in the if clause.. :(

Comment: Then you need to debug why that doesn't happen. Are you getting the exact same text from the file, does it have some additional whitespace or a typo?

Comment: At the time of debugging first it stops on "if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey"))" line and then it directly come to the "else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click"))". After this it again go to the loop of objectRepository.

Comment: When it does that, what's the value of `operation`?

Comment: When it does means? It happens when it come to the if() clause and the value of "operation" is (Value=(id=44)) and its value is 1.

Comment: Then there's an issue in your `ExcelHandler` or in your .xls, since `operation` should have value of "SendKey" instead of 1, to hit that if clause.

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote (and possibly accept) it and if the solution wasn't exactly described here, post the resolution in your own answer & accept it. That way this question can help others too. Unresolved questions that got solved, but not documented are quite annoying for others facing similar issues.

Comment: See this things are missing: 1.Missing Mapping Between OR(objectRepository) file and test suite file via Framework name. 2.
We have to get Framework name from Test Scenario and from OR search Framework name (Locator, ObjectName, Get Page object value). 3. For login workbook we don't get the columnData from has table.
I am posting working code have a look below.

Answer (score -1):

@user2092132- You require to make changes on two places in your code

1: Insert new line after line-  System.out.println("Total Rows="+rowCount);
WebDriver driver = null;

2:Change line from: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb,new FirefoxProfile());
To: driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb,new FirefoxProfile());

Above two changes should resolve initiating new instacne of FF each time.